# Which is preferred for xml data display? Jquery or xslt?

Tags: jquery, xml, ajax

I need to use my xml files(xml data) and present them so that a common man can understand it

ex: if my xml file has library of books and i want to extract some data like author, title,etc and display this data in a more readable format.

so which one is more apt for this kind of application? Jquery or xslt?

Comment: Do you even know what jQuery and "Ajax" *are*? How about you go find out the meanings of those words, and then come back to delete your question.

Comment: Ajax is to jQuery as driving is to Ford. You can't choose *between* them. You can drive a Ford car. You can drive a Renault car. You can sit in a Ford car listening to the radio without driving it anywhere. (Then the analogy breaks down as there are plenty of other things you can do with jQuery that are as important to jQuery as Ajax)

Comment: This is a tough one... jay queery is good for stuff, but aye jacks can do some other stuff purdy good. I'd chose neither.

Comment: Learn more buzzwords and then ask more questions. Every day needs more humor.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Both and neither. XML is data, and you must obtain it and manipulate it somehow.

You can fetch it with AJAX. You can manipulate it with jQuery. You can display it to your users using HTML and you can make it look good using CSS.

Know your weapons and use them accordingly.

Answer (score 5):

Try using XSLT, a stylesheet language for XML documents.  There is a nice tutorial at http://www.w3schools.com/xsl/

Comment: It is actually any good? I don't know XSLT so I can't judge it myself, but if is of the same quality as W3Schools' materials on subjects I do understand, then I wouldn't touch it with a long barge pole.

Comment: it is, but barge mileage may vary - especially without a long pole